# Что же нужно вставлять в портфолио?

Tags: unity3d

Хотелось бы больше информации, что конкретно или желательно вставить.Unity, разработчик. Может быть советом помогли бы.

Comment: По идее, нужно сперва долго брать заказы от более мелких к более крупным, и более мелкие будут портфолио к более крупным. Но...

Comment: ...но мне, например, мои комплексы не позволяют вставлять туда 95-100% своих проектов, которые не блещут ни функционалом, ни нужностью человечеству, ни, тем более, качеством кода. Не вставляю, а только показываю по запросу... Вероятно, в таком случае ситуацию могут выручить свои pet project'ы - там проще дотянуть все до того или иного уровня и именно в том векторе, было бы время и жрат.

Comment: @SmInc, Но, толку от этого портфолио не будет, потому что работодателя нужно убедить навыками или же мышлением, к примеру.

Answer (score 2):

- Образование если оно способствует работе по этой специальности.
- Бэкграунд, если он в смежной области.
- Список навыков и компетенций. Конкретно, перечисляем все более или менее значимое в контексте вакансии на которую претендуем.
- Проекты к которым приложил руку. Чем завершенней они выглядят, тем лучше. Под остальными не стесняемся, пишем: "Не опубликованы".

Опционально, но желательно:

- Линки на аккаунт github, stackoveflow и прочее. Ссылки на сертификаты
  повышения квалификации и прочие приблуды.

p.s. когда пойдете на собеседование, не поленитесь, распечатайте свое резюме в нескольких вариантах. Сэкономит время, произведет неплохое впечатление.

Comment: а для чего линк на аккаунт stackoveflow?

Comment: если он "прокачен" это косвенное свидетельство о "компетентности"